# Refreshing ad manager ads on SPA (single page application)

Tags: refresh, ads, display, page-refresh, adx

If I have a SPA pages (single page application)
So when the user go from one page to another , the page doesn't benign refreshed (while the URL is changing)

If it was a regular html website , on every new page all the ads will benign queried and refreshed again , while on SPA it doesn't happen as the ad doesn't know it's a new page.

Now I have display ads on the pages (ad manager units)

So how can I make the ad manager unit be refreshed on every new page on a SPA website ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am also facing this issue. DId you solve the problem?